# Items not added to arraylist

Tags: java, user-interface

I am trying to add flowers to a `flowerpack` and they are not being added. The first part is a GUI, but once "Enter new flower" is checked it switches to console. All of the console print lines appear and I enter information, but I placed a breakpoint at the `flowerpack.add` and it never gets reached, so my `flowerpack` is always empty. What am I doing wrong here?

```
private static void addFlower(ArrayList<Plant> flowerPack)  {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("HelloWorldSwing");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    JLabel flowerLabel = new JLabel("Enter new flower: ");
    frame.getContentPane().add(flowerLabel);
    JCheckBox checkFlower = new JCheckBox();
    frame.getContentPane().add(checkFlower);
    checkFlower.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 

            System.out.print("Please enter flower ID: ");
            int plantID = in.nextInt();
            in.nextLine(); 
            System.out.print("Please enter flower Name: ");
            String flowerName = in.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Please enter flower color: ");
            String flowerColor = in.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Does flower have thorns? Yes or no: ");
            String flowerThorns = in.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Does flower smell? Yes or no: ");
            String flowerSmell = in.nextLine();

            flowerPack.add(new Flower(plantID, flowerName,
                flowerColor, flowerThorns, flowerSmell));
        } 
    });
```

Comment: If the statement doesn't execute then it means the `in.nextLine()` is waiting for user input. If you are creating a GUI then don't use a Scanner to get user input. Instead you can use a [JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) to prompt for user input.

Comment: Could you amend your question to include the actual output, ie. what appears on the console.